# Bootstrap Rows won't align properly

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently having some issues with the bootstrap row layout. In the code below I am trying to align the address beneath the location section. For some reason it displays in the column next to location.

However when I put a border:solid style into the address section it aligns as I want it to. Wondering if anyone can see any issues with this code.

```html
<div class="row-fluid" id="contact-location">
    <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" id="map">
        <h3><strong style="text-align:center"><b><u>Location</u></b></strong></h3>
        <div>
            <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2385.4505439345817!2d-6.336240884814465!3d53.2814638872712!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x48670b168669ec2b%3A0x2d6785ebb4929856!2s94+Woodlawn+Park+Grove%2C+Dublin+24!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sie!4v1445292277523" width="100%" height="315" style="border:0; text-align:center" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            <!-- Google Map containing home address -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid" id="contact-address">
    <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" id="address">
        <!-- printed address with contact numbers -->
        <h3><strong style="text-align:center;"><b><u>Address</u></b></strong></h3>
        <address style="text-align:center">
            <strong>Mr. XXXX XXXX</strong>
            <br> XX XXXXXXXXXX,
            <br> XXXXXXX,
            <br> XXXXX,
            <br> XXXXXX
            <br>
            <b>Mobile:</b>
            <br>
            <b>Home:</b>
        </address>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: this doesn't have anything to do w/ your problem, but try and use bootstrap already pre-defined CSS, such as `class="text-center"`. Also instead of all those `<br/>` and `<b>`, etc - use some CSS - it'll make your code cleaner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly you're trying to center the map with the address information at all times.

If that's the case you just need to adjust the way you're utilizing the grid. `Row-fluid` isn't used in Bootstrap 3, use `row` (this will solve most of the problem) and instead of using empty `columns` like this `<div class="col-sm-4"></div>`, use 12 columns or an [offset](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting) `<div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">.` You can also use two separate rows or one for this since you're occupying the entire space.

- Also, this article may interest you > [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/strong) The HTML Strong Element (`<strong>`) gives text strong importance, and is typically displayed in bold.

Hopefully this helps.

See working Snippet.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row text-center" id="contact-location">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3" id="map">
      <h3><strong><b><u>Location</u></b></strong></h3>

      <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2385.4505439345817!2d-6.336240884814465!3d53.2814638872712!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x48670b168669ec2b%3A0x2d6785ebb4929856!2s94+Woodlawn+Park+Grove%2C+Dublin+24!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sie!4v1445292277523"
      width="100%" height="315" style="border:0; text-align:center" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3" id="address">
      <h3><strong><b><u>Address</u></b></strong></h3>
      <address>
            <strong><b>Mr. XXXX XXXX</b></strong>
            <br> XX XXXXXXXXXX,
            <br> XXXXXXX,
            <br> XXXXX,
            <br> XXXXXX
            <br>
            <b>Mobile:</b>
            <br>
            <b>Home:</b>
        </address>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`strong` is an inline element. You have to apply `text-align: center` to block level elements (in your case `h3`).

```
<h3 style="text-align:center;"><strong><b><u>Address</u></b></strong></h3>
```